# Sort panda data frame on multiple columns, where ASC/DESC is based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
             city  crime  pollution  ...  housing  weather  Similarity
0      Atlanta GA    101         97  ...      119       60        2.75
2    Baltimore MD    103        126  ...      103       80        2.50
4  San Antonio TX     98        126  ...      100       65        2.50
1        Akron OH    100        119  ...       97       70        1.75
3   Charleston SC    106        127  ...       82       75        1.50
```

---

I want to first sort based on Similarity, descending. Got that code:

```
df.sort_values('Similarity', ascending=False)
```

But if there is a tie, I want to sort based on a user input list. Of the 8 columns in my data, users can add UP TO 5 to the preference list, which is stored in order of adding it:

```
userPrefs = [] 
# ex: userPrefs = ['crime','education','weather','pollution']
```

So if there is a tie (such as between df[2] and df[4]), I need the code to then sort based on the list. Got that code:

```
df.sort_values(userPrefs[0], ascending=False).sort_values(userPrefs[1], ascending=False) # -- etc...
  .sort_values('Similarity', ascending=False)
```

The issue I'm facing is that depending on the column added to userPrefs, the sorting may need to be ascending or it may need to be descending. So if `'crime' == userPref[0]`, I want it to be ASC (lowest crime is best); however, if `'education' == userPref[0]`, I want to sort DESC (higher education is best).

How do I sort based on a condition? I was thinking :

```
ascList = ['crime','housing','pollution'] # the lower, the better
descList = ['education'] # the higher, the better

df.sort_values(userPrefs[0], ascending= if x in ascList)
```

..but that doesn't work and I'm not clear on lambda functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need lambda functions, create parameters `by=` and `ascending=` of the function `.sort_values()` on the fly:

```py
# use sets here:
ascList = {"crime", "housing", "pollution"}
descList = {"education"}

# example userPrefs:
userPrefs = ["crime", "weather", "pollution"]


df = df.sort_values(
    by=["Similarity", *userPrefs], ascending=[False, *[p in ascList for p in userPrefs]]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             city  crime  pollution  housing  weather  Similarity
0      Atlanta GA    101         97      119       60        2.75
4  San Antonio TX     98        126      100       65        2.50
2    Baltimore MD    103        126      103       80        2.50
1        Akron OH    100        119       97       70        1.75
3   Charleston SC    106        127       82       75        1.50
```

Comment: Sets would be more efficient for large datasets. Note descList is not required. +1

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for the added reminder to use sets for quicker searching :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify lists of `by` and `ascending` values to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) so you can specify how each of the `userPrefs` should be sorted based on their presence in `ascList`:

```py
userPrefs = ['crime','weather','pollution']
ascList = ['crime','housing','pollution'] # the lower, the better

df.sort_values(by=['Similarity']+userPrefs, ascending=[False]+[u in ascList for u in userPrefs])
```

Output for your sample data:

```
             city  crime  pollution  housing  weather  Similarity
0      Atlanta GA    101         97      119       60        2.75
4  San Antonio TX     98        126      100       65        2.50
2    Baltimore MD    103        126      103       80        2.50
1        Akron OH    100        119       97       70        1.75
3   Charleston SC    106        127       82       75        1.50
```

Note as @AndrejKesely points out in their answer, sets are more efficient for lookup than lists.

Comment: but perhaps the ascList/descList should be sets (not that it matters, they are small). +1 :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely agreed, sets would be more efficient for large data but there's only 8 columns. Also I like to keep my code as similar to OP as possible where it doesn't have a major impact.